# Медленная передача файлов с linux-сервера

Tags: linux, windows, centos, ssh, ftp

Сервер с centos 6.4.
Если отправляю файлы с сервера на внешнее хранилище (windows-машина с FTP и SSH сервисами), при помощи `lftp` или `scp -r` то передача идет на скорости около 500 КБ/сек.

Если подключаюсь к windows-машине и с неё при помощи `WinSCP` по scp забираю файлы с сервера - то скорость взлетает до 40 мегабит.

10 файлов, от 100МБ до 8ГБ. Суммарный объем около 12ГБ.
Канал около 50 мегабит.

Куда копать? Как ускорить отправку файлов?

Скрин производительности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление**

Сравнил загрузку процессора на обоих машинах при передаче обоими способами, разница незначительная - в пределах 10 % (Что, на мой взгляд, можно отнести к погрешности).

Если на windows машину лить файлы не с сервера, а еще откуда нибудь тоже медленно. Хотя "windows - машинка" достаточно мощная и шустрая. Нагрузки на процессор почти нет, памяти свободной около 70% (Общий объем 8ГБ).

Почему может возникать такая разница в скорости передачи данных в зависимости от инициатора?

При передаче с сервера на другую машину в сети - со скоростью всё хорошо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при отправке с другой машины на windows- очень медленная передача.

**Обновление 2**

Я пробовал передавать при помощи lftp, подключаясь к опубликованному на той же машине (IIS) ftp-серверу. Ситуация примерно такая же. Может сможете посоветовать хороший ssh/scp сервер для windows? Сейчас используется Bitvise SSH server.

Comment: Загрузку процессора на обоих машинах при передаче обоими способами сравните

Comment: А если _на_ windows машину лить файлы не с сервера, а еще откуда нибудь.

Comment: Я бы предложил попробовать на винде поднять какое нибудь другое средство приема файлови посмотреть разницу. Идей от чего так происходит нет. Кроме тех что виновата сама принимающая программа-сервер

Comment: Попробуйте загрузить какой-нибудь *linux-liveCD* на windows-машине и организовать прием/отправку, чтобы убедиться, что на аппаратном уровне всё в порядке. А в случае с windows, скорей всего, придется использовать *samba*...

Comment: какая сеть продожена между этими двумя машинами? Может быть, у провайдера просто настроены хитрые правила управления трафиком? Можно попробовать поднять FTP на том же порту, куда стучится winscp?

Comment: С live-cd дистрибутивом мысль здравая, спасибо. Но сложность в том, что это удаленная машина и у меня нет к ней физического доступа. Думаю попробовать запустить виртуалку на vmware workstation с, например, DSL-linux. Между машинами много разных промежуточных точек и интернет. На счёт хитрых правил управления трафиком - врятли. У меня трафик идёт в любом случае в сторону win-машины. На счёт поднять ftp - а зачем? winscp стучится по 22 (ssh/scp) порту на linux сервер и прекрасно (Очень быстро) забирает данные с него.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответа на вопрос "Почему так" не нашёл. 
Сделал костыль, который позволил обойти проблему.

На windows установил ssh сервер.
С Linux отправляю на windows по ssh команду забрать файлы с Linux по scp при помощи WinSCP cli.
Жуткая конструкция, но работает.